# Why runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests on true when using Systme.Web.Routing.Route

Tags: webforms, url-routing, routetable

Based on an article of Scott Hanselman we always had the option runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests on false in our Webforms project.

Also we have a few routes.MapPageRoute configurations running succesfully.

Now we need to add ICS (internet calendar) support to our webform project. To create a clean, readable url for the users, which could be handled by a IHttpHandler, I've added the following:

```
routes.Add(new Route("ical/{username}/{somecheck}", new ICalHandler()));
```

Now, the url is the way we want it, like this:

```
http://foo.com/ical/username/abc.ics
```

On localhost (VS2012, Windows 8) the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests can be on false.

On the testserver (Win2k8 R2, IIS7.5) I get a "Page Not Found" error. But, when I enable runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests, it works.

If it has to be this way, so be it. But I would realy like to know why... Can anyone explain why I need to enable this setting?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

an update that was made to IIS 7 makes the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests setting unnecessary and supports ASP.NET routing natively. (For information about the update, see the Microsoft Support article An update is available that enables certain IIS 7.0 or IIS 7.5 handlers to handle requests whose URLs do not end with a period.)
If your website is running on IIS 7 and if IIS has been updated, you do not need to set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true. In fact, setting it to true is not recommended, because it adds unnecessary processing overhead to request. When this setting is true, all requests, including those for .htm, .jpg, and other static files, also go through the ASP.NET request pipeline.
The default setting for runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is false. If the site's configuration file does not explicitly set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true, when you then run the website on Windows 7 without SP1 installed, IIS 7 will not include the required update. As a consequence, routing will not work and you will see errors. If you have a problem where routing does not work, you can do the following:
Update Windows 7 to SP1, which will add the update to IIS 7.
Install the update that's described in the Microsoft Support article listed previously.
Set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true in that website's Web.config file. Note that this will add some overhead to requests.